# Dockerfile "RUN echo" with redirect command results in Mangled Filename

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
WORKDIR /etc/apache2/conf-enabled
RUN ln -s ../conf-available/lda-htaccess.conf .
WORKDIR /etc/apache2/conf-available
RUN echo "<Directory /var/www/html>\n" \
         "  AllowOverride All\n" \
         "</Directory>\n" \
         > lda-htaccess.conf
```

And here is the resulting directory entry:

```
root@866474a33e66:/etc/apache2/conf-available# ls -al
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 11 18:12  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Sep 12 09:38  ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  315 Apr  2  2019  charset.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  204 Sep 12 09:38  docker-php.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3224 Apr  2  2019  localized-error-pages.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Apr  2  2019  other-vhosts-access-log.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2174 Apr  2  2019  security.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  455 Apr  2  2019  serve-cgi-bin.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Oct 11 18:12 ''$'\302\240''lda-htaccess.conf'
root@866474a33e66:/etc/apache2/conf-available#
```

It doesn't seem to matter how I format the echo command, or if I use the exec form, or what content I use; it's always the same result.

Here is my version:

Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like this should work - and I've used this pattern before.

Comment: Please provide your complete Dockerfile or at least say what the base image is.

Comment: I did - but the first line wasn't displayed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a unicode space character after the > and before the filename. Fixing that fixed the Dockerfile build. There was no error in my syntax.

Comment: This falls into the category of a problem that "could not be reproduced or was caused by a typographical error". Such questions should be deleted.